# Delete argument from command

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, powershell, readline, interactive

If I have a commandline like this:

```
sunday.exe monday tuesday-wednesday
```

I would like to delete to the last space, or essentially the last argument. I tried `Ctrl + Backspace`, but it deletes only to the first hyphen. Is this possible?

Comment: You would have to change what power shell command line uses for word boundaries. I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view current delimiters:

```
(get-PSReadLIneOption).WordDelimiters
```

To remove the "-" character (current session):

```
(get-PSREadLIneOption).WordDelimiters = (get-PSREadLIneOption).WordDelimiters -replace '-'
```

To restore defaults:

```
(get-PSREadLIneOption).WordDelimiters = @'
;:,.[]{}()/\|^&*-=+'"–—―
'@
```

Answer (score 1):

Not something native in PowerShell.

You'd have to mess with PSReadline customizations.

> about_PSReadLine
>
> **BackwardWord**
>
> Move the cursor back to the start of the current word, or if between words, the start of the previous word. Word
> boundaries are defined by a configurable set of characters.
>
> Cmd: <Ctrl+LeftArrow> Emacs: <Alt+b>, <Escape,b> Vi insert mode:
> <Ctrl+LeftArrow> Vi command mode: <Ctrl+LeftArrow>
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/about/about_psreadline?view=powershell-7

And remember that PSReadline is only a consolehost thing, not the ISE or VSCode which would require separate configuration or add-on.